# Modal background is overlaying the components inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

So, I am creating this React component modal to display the comments made inside each post. So far, so good. The only issue is that when I set the height of the modal's background, it immediately overlays everything. I have tried everything to solve this problem, such as adjusting the z-index, positions, and so on, but nothing has worked. I'm feeling quite desperate because this issue has already cost me hours and hours of work, thinking, and research, and I have not yet come up with a solution.

Here's the component:

```
import { CommentsModalStyled } from "../../../styles/commentsModal";

interface CommentsInterface {
    comments: any[];
  }
  
  export const CommentsModal = ({ comments }: CommentsInterface) => {


    return (
        <CommentsModalStyled>
            <div className="modalBackground">
                <div className="commentsContainer">
                    {comments.length !== 0 ? (
                    comments.map((e: any, index: number) => (
                        <div className="commentsSection" key={index}>
                        <div className="commentsSection--image">
                            <img src={e.user.perfil} alt="userphoto" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="commentsSection--content">
                            <span>{e.text}</span>
                            <span>{e.created_at}</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                    ) : null}
                </div>

            </div>
      </CommentsModalStyled>
    );
  };
```

and here's the styled component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const CommentsModalStyled = styled.div`

.modalBackground {
    background-color: #00000038;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;

}

.commentsContainer {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.commentsSection {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.commentsSection--image > img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 51px;
    

}

`
```

Here is what it look like when i set no height to class=modalBackground:

[image]

Here's what happens when i set it's height to 100%:

[image]

Can somone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one make the modal container fixed then the main is position relative then put z index so it were not go over the other container
you can try this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these at once? Seems like after setting the 100% height the `commentsContainer` is getting at the top. So trying to send it backward and bringing the `commentsSection` at the top.

```
.commentsContainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.commentsSection {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: I did try it but it didn't worked either

Answer (score 0):

try to give min-height to it and set height to fit-content and order the z-index

```
    .commentsContainer {
      min-height: 60%;
      height:fit-content
      z-index: 2;
        }
    .commentsSection{
          z-index: 3;
        }
```